# Global Axis/View weirdly tilted

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I'm having quite an unusual problem with Blender. The global axis of my entire scene is oddly rotated/tilted, when moving around the tilt stays the same.

I think it's best described through a picture:

[image]

You can see that even the axis in the bottom left of the 3D view is tilted.

How do I get out of this view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> while rotating the Mouse Wheel to rotate your view:

[image]

Or Press <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>  to go back to Front view or  <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> for Left view...

Comment: Ahh so simple, thanks a lot, this is a lifesaver for (the noob) me!

Answer (score 5):

## Blender 2.80+

You have your camera *rolled* i.e. it's been rotated around *its* Z-axis.  In [Blender 2.83 the keyboard shortcuts to roll](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#roll) left and right are <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> respectively.

Alternatively, you can go to one of the orthographic views (e.g. <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) and then click-drag your <kbd>MMB</kbd> to rotate back to the more familiar perspective view without roll.

With the slew of interface changes in Blender 2.80, I think the mouse shortcuts were removed.  I'm not able to roll the viewport using the mouse.