# Why aren't objects in my viewport straight / parallel to my screen?

Tags: 3d-view

It seems that the 3D view within which I am working shows me the scene in a slightly angled / rotated way.

For example this TV Set is built from a cube, I never rotated it (just added cuts, etc). I added straight lines to explain what I mean:

[image: object canted in 3D view]

It doesn't matter what object in the scene I look at, or how much I zoom back and forth or move things left or right, everything always seem to be slightly angled like that, even when starting scenes from a new file.

Quite annoying especially since I often align the camera to view, which then produces non-parallel camera angles.

Here is a GIF file reproducing the problem, right from the Startup File's cube:

[image]

Comment: Hello. I may say things you know. You have pressed numeric keypad views such as (1,3,7,9) and for othogonal view 5?  Can we see a picture of when you add a standard cube or uv sphere?

Comment: If you are on user perspective view it makes sense. On perspective view, If you look at things at an angle, parallel lines will point towards a vanishing point.. Use one of the preset views like front/back right/left.  For a perfectly perpendicular view use orthogonal view.

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46688/global-axis-view-weirdly-tilted/46689#46689

Comment: Thanks all. No numeric keypad on my 3d workstation (MacBook Pro). Cegaton, good comment... although, why is it angled in this direction even when I pan from the left to the right of the object and even when I rotate around it? Why not tilted the other way around? Impossible to tell if other question is related, pressing HOLD and SHIFT rotates the scene a LOT more than I need to straighten it.

Comment: The view menu has the same choices such as front, back etc.  The numeric keypad is not a requirement to get the view.  The least expensive usb keypad I have was $6.  It is entirely worth it.  Testing the standard cube, which by default is axis aligned, is a more trustworthy test.

Comment: @fabriced If you don't have a numeric pad you can still access the preset views on the menu: http://i.stack.imgur.com/STrDB.png

Comment: Try aligning the view to the active plane, then aligning the camera to the current view. "View>>Align View>>Align View To Active>>Top" Then "View>>Align View>>Align Active Camera To View". If it comes out 90° from expected, you can always rotate the camera.

Comment: All these combined give good solutions to *fix* the slanting of the scene (although I can't accept them as answers since they are comments). I'm still not sure how every one of my projects end up skewed ("Turntable" mode is on, not "Trackball"). I've expanded my question with a GIF reproducing the problem starting from the Startup File cube.

Comment: The fastest way to make 3D view being aligned as by default is to enter some orthographic preset view (like `Numpad 1`) and exit it with `MMB`. I'm not sure is there any "skew" in your gif (probably that's [perspective distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_projection_distortion), however perspective view is far from the best one to judge straight lines, orthographic is used for that (`Numpad 5`).

Comment: Thanks @MrZak, I know now how to fix the issue, I am interested in understanding *why* it shifts -1° on view axis after I create and move some objects around